# Rotate objects around their origin along a global axis (scripted) without bpy.ops

Tags: python, objects, transforms

I have read so much about Blender rotation in the last two hours that my head is spinning, but I can not understand how to rotate strictly in **global** coordinates without using `bpy.ops`. In reality I will have a large number of objects and do this frequently, so I'd like to use a rotation method of the objects themselves, like one of these: `obj.rotate_euler()` or `obj.matrix_world *= some_vector` or `obj.rotation_axis_angle()`

but I don't understand how to use them for strictly single **global** axis rotations like the following example:

```
import bpy
import math

half_pi = 0.5 * math.pi

group = []
for y in [-3, 0, 3]:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(location=(0, y, 0)) # ops is OK here, but not in the rotations
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    group.append(obj)

zangles = [1, 1.5, 2] # radains

for obj, zangle in zip(group, zangles):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj.select = True
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=half_pi, axis=(1, 0, 0))  # rotate about global X by 90 degrees
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=zangle,  axis=(0, 0, 1))  # rotate about global Z by zangle

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

`ops` can rotate globally, but I don't see any methods associated with objects to to global rotation, and I can't figure out how to do that.

A link to a less theoretical, and more "if you want to do this, use this" scripted rotation explanation would also be greatly appreciated. I'm OK with the math, it's the *Blender conventions* I can not get a handle on.

[image: rotated cylinders]

Comment: If you are ok with the math, then adjusting the world matrix shouldn't be a problem. There are no blender specific conventions I can think of.

Comment: I don't find "world matrix" in the index of my math book. "*OK with*" means what I don't understand mathematically, I can look up. It does *not* mean I'm a math genius.  I'm trying to explain which kind of tutorial would be the most helpful to me right now.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

TL;DR > Skip to last paragraph

Each object has it's own World Matrix. It's a 4x4 transform matrix that stores the object's final location, rotation and scale. By doing math operations directly on this matrix we can transform the object how ever we want.

Every world matrix can be decomposed into it's components:

```
loc, rot, scale = obj.matrix_world.decompose()
```

We get a

- location vector (size 3)
- rotation quaternion (size 4)
- scale vector (size 3)

Now about rotations. A rotation is either represented by a (3x3 or 4x4) [Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) (Euler or Matrix class in Blender), [Quaternion vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) (Quaternion class) or an axis (Vector of size 3) with rotation value (radians). They can be all converted between each other, but we just need the 4x4 rotation matrix. There are different options to construct it:

```
from mathutils import Matrix, Euler, Quaternion

# directly
Matrix.Rotation(angle, 4, axis)

# converting from Euler matrix
Euler((angleX, angleY, angleZ), 'XYZ').to_4x4()

# converting from quaternion
Quaternion((w, x, y, z)).to_matrix().to_4x4()
```

Transformations are done with [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) and the order in which they are multiplied is important, as the operation is not commutative. Doing:

```
matA @ matB @ matC
```

means the result will be like first transforming with `matC`, then `matB` and last `matA` (it's reversed from how you multiply them).
All the transformations are **applied** in **global** space.

Here you can see what it looks like to do `Translation @ Rotation` (on the left) and `Rotation @ Translation` (on the right):

[image]

The first end-result we can substitute with a local translation and then local rotation, and the second we can substitute with a local rotation and then local translation. This means only the first matrix (`matA`) will represent a global transformation in the end, because all the others were influenced by it.

This is how a *World Matrix* is composed. The order is again important:

```
matrix_world = matLoc @ matRot @ matScale
```

To alter it and to add an extra global rotation, we need to sneak our rotation matrix between `matRot` and `matLoc` (so it's applied as last rotation = in global space):

```
new_matrix_world = origLoc @ matRot @ origRot @ origScale
```

Here's an example code:

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from mathutils import Matrix

# example on an active object
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# define some rotation
angle_in_degrees = 45
rot_mat = Matrix.Rotation(radians(angle_in_degrees), 4, 'X')   # you can also use as axis Y,Z or a custom vector like (x,y,z)

# decompose world_matrix's components, and from them assemble 4x4 matrices
orig_loc, orig_rot, orig_scale = obj.matrix_world.decompose()
orig_loc_mat = Matrix.Translation(orig_loc)
orig_rot_mat = orig_rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
orig_scale_mat = Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[0],4,(1,0,0)) * Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[1],4,(0,1,0)) @ Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[2],4,(0,0,1))

# assemble the new matrix
obj.matrix_world = orig_loc_mat @ rot_mat @ orig_rot_mat @ orig_scale_mat
```

Comment: your explanation is extremely helpful! It will take me some hours to go through it carefully. I am always amazed at the amount of math" under the hood" in Blender. Thank you for taking the time to go into this so deeply!

Comment: ...hmmm and so how do I rotate my cylinder sequentially, first by 90 degrees about **global_X** and then by 57 degrees (1 radian) around **global_Z**  as asked in the question? I'm learning to appreciate that location, rotation and scale are combined in `obj.matrix_world` and seeing how you take it a part and put it back together is really very informative. But I still want to know how to do a series of two rotations of an object around **global axes** without using ops.

Comment: @uhoh sequentially like you want to see the results inbetween or you just want to do this composite rotation of first transforming with *globalX* and then *globalZ* (which in matrix math is *globalZ * globalX*). ?

Comment: Yes, just the final result of what those two global rotations would produce if executed sequentially - first about **global_X**, then about **global_Z**.

Comment: @uhoh then that's `obj.matrix_world = orig_loc_mat * global_Z * global_X * orig_rot_mat * orig_scale_mat`.

Comment: thank you for sticking with me here @Jerryno! Yep That works! It's about 6 lines and 14us, which is Great! My starting point (using `ops`) was two lines, but 400us! So again there is a performance advantage to using the methods associated with the objects themselves, and avoiding using `ops`.

Comment: use ```obj.matrix_world = orig_loc_mat @ rot_mat @ orig_rot_mat @ orig_scale_mat``` for 2.8 and above

Comment: best explanation ever

Answer (score 7):

Refining [Ruslan's solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74719/5334) using 2.8 syntax:

```
def rotate_object(obj, angle_degrees, axis='Z'):
    ''' rotates an object '''
    from math import radians
    from mathutils import Matrix

    # local rotation about axis
    obj.rotation_euler = (obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix() @ Matrix.Rotation(radians(angle_degrees), 3, axis)).to_euler()
```

Answer (score 6):

One line rotation:

```
from mathutils import Matrix
import math

obj = bpy.context.active_object
# rotate around global Z-axis
obj.rotation_euler = (Matrix.Rotation(math.pi, 3, 'Z') * obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix()).to_euler()
# or around local axis
obj.rotation_euler = (obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix() * Matrix.Rotation(math.pi, 3, 'Z')).to_euler()
```

Jerryno already explained the sequence of multiplication.

Comment: OK I'll give it a whirl when I get to a keyboard. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in 2.8

Comment: @hatinacat2000 this has now been addressed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188056/5334)

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you need?

```
import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Matrix

half_pi = 0.5 * math.pi

group = []
for y in [-3, 0, 3]:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(location=(0, y, 0)) # ops is OK here, but not in the rotations
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    group.append(obj)

# use the Matrix.Rotation constructor to create a rotation matrix
# half_pi: rotation angle
# 4: matrix size, in this case we will create a 4x4 matrix. 3 and 2 are also valid values for creating 3x3 and 2x2 matrices 
# X: axis about which we want to rotate
hpiMat = Matrix.Rotation(half_pi, 4, 'X')

print (hpiMat)

# do the same again for the individual zangle rotations
aMat = Matrix.Rotation(1, 4, 'Z')
bMat = Matrix.Rotation(1.5, 4, 'Z')
cMat = Matrix.Rotation(2, 4, 'Z')

print (aMat)
print (bMat)
print (cMat)

zangles = [aMat, bMat, cMat] # list of zangle rotation matrices

for obj, zangle in zip(group, zangles):

    # construct the final rotation matrix for the object by multiplying the half pi matrix with the current zangle matrix
    finalMat = zangle * hpiMat

    # mulitply the final rotation matrix against the object's world matrix
    obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world * finalMat
```

also gives the output:

```
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (0.5403, -0.8415, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.8415,  0.5403, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (0.0707, -0.9975, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.9975,  0.0707, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.4161, -0.9093, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            ( 0.9093, -0.4161, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
```

Comment: Excellent! Yes indeed it does. So in `Matrix.Rotation(1, 4, 'Z')` does the 'Z' always refer to global coordinates? No matter what else I might do?

Comment: From what I can see, 'Z' doesn't always refer to global Z. E.g. if you rotate your object about the X axis in the 3d viewport, and then using the python console, you multiply the matrix_world with a Z rotation matrix like above, you'll see that the object isn't rotated about global Z. One way around this is to apply the first rotation before rotating in python. To apply rotation, first set the active object and then use: bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False). Now try the Z rotation again, and the object will be roatated about global Z. Does that make sense?

Comment: @uhoh the 'Z' does mean global Z axis in the context of matrix. You can also use any 3D vector instead as a rotation axis. What matters is the rotation order. If you rotate around Z and then around X, the Z rotation will be global. Vice-versa it will be local. The order you multiply the matrices defines the rotation order.

Comment: OK I think I see, so it seems that the script above works in this case, but it's not a bullet-proof recipe for **strictly global** rotations? Is this all explained/defined clearly somewhere, or are you folks finding this out by trial and error?

Comment: @uhoh Yes you are right, the script above works only in this case. It is clearly defined if you google *Rotation Matrix* on wiki and also see what a *World Matrix* is made of. I might write a bit math answer in about an hour (can't now) to explain how exacly does this work and appropriate blender commands to do the math operations.

Comment: @Jerryno Could you supply a particular, definitive link? Google is very big. You can't say something is "clearly defined in Google." I love to read math - indeed I prefer it to plain text! Please post some in an answer. What does "on wiki" mean?

Comment: @uhoh for example this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix. I'll make an blender specific answer, it's not well documented here.

Comment: @fergal thank you for your help! I'm sorry but I've removed the "accepted" status to your answer - I'm still looking for the sequence of strictly global rotations.

Comment: No worries mate, sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also parent the object in an empty set it's rotation there and let the system computer the exact same thing through the parent chain but you also get animation etc. as a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44783/131649),
Incase anyone wants to change the global rotation **TO** a certain orientation
and not **BY**

( what's the difference? in **by** you "add" to your existing rotation, in **to** you directly "=" the new rotation )

```
import bpy,math
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector


def global_rotation_matrix(x_deg=0,y_deg=0,z_deg=0,order="XYZ",size=4): # matrix= size x size
    
    # creating unit vector based on size
    unit_matrix=[]
    for i in range(size):
        axis_vector=[]
        for j in range(size):
            if(i==j):
                axis_vector.append(1)
            else:
                axis_vector.append(0)
        unit_matrix.append(axis_vector)
    
    # creating new global rotation matrix
    new_matrix=[]
    for vec in unit_matrix:
        vec=Vector(vec)
        for axis in reversed(order):
            if(axis=="X" or axis=="x"):
                vec=vec @ Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(x_deg),size, 'X')
            elif(axis=="Y" or axis=="y"):
                vec=vec @ Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(y_deg), size, 'Y')
            elif(axis=="Z" or axis=="z"):
                vec=vec @ Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(z_deg), size, 'Z')
        new_matrix.append(vec)
        
    return Matrix(new_matrix)

def global_rotate_obj(obj,x_deg=0,y_deg=0,z_deg=0,order="XYZ"):
    orig_loc, orig_rot, orig_scale = obj.matrix_world.decompose()
    orig_loc_mat = Matrix.Translation(orig_loc)
    orig_scale_mat = Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[0], 4, (1, 0, 0)) * Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[1], 4, (0, 1, 0)) @ Matrix.Scale(orig_scale[2], 4, (0, 0, 1))
    
    obj.matrix_world = orig_loc_mat @ global_rotation_matrix(x_deg,y_deg,z_deg,order) @ orig_scale_mat


obj=bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
global_rotate_obj(obj,10,0,0)
```

or using [EMCS's solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188056/131649) & simplifying further:

```
import bpy,math
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

def global_rotation_matrix(x_deg=0,y_deg=0,z_deg=0,order="XYZ",size=4): # matrix= size x size

    # creating unit vector based on size
    unit_matrix=[ [1 if i==j else 0 for j in range(size)] for i in range(size) ]

    # creating new global rotation matrix
    new_matrix=[]
    for vec in unit_matrix:
        vec=Vector(vec)
        for axis in reversed(order):
            if(axis=="X" or axis=="x"):
                vec=vec @ Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(x_deg),size, 'X')
            elif(axis=="Y" or axis=="y"):
                vec=vec @ Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(y_deg), size, 'Y')
            elif(axis=="Z" or axis=="z"):
                vec=vec @ Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(z_deg), size, 'Z')
        new_matrix.append(vec)

    return Matrix(new_matrix)

obj=bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
obj.rotation_euler = global_rotation_matrix(30,0,10).to_euler()
```

Comment: *Excellent*, thank you!