# Script Rotation around global axis

Tags: python

It seems I've been generous on questions lately. But being a Blender newbie it can't be helped.

I was wondering if there is a simple way of rotating an object around a global axis (or any other axis, such as the ones I defined in the custom frame) using a python script.

I read a decent explanation here, but I was wondering if I am missing something:

[Rotate objects around their origin along a global axis (scripted) without bpy.ops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44760/rotate-objects-around-their-origin-along-a-global-axis-scripted-without-bpy-op)

What I mean is, if it is possible to simply rotate an object in the blender in 3d View around any of the global axis, then shouldn't there be a simple command in python which allows to specify which frame I want to rotate in (global, local, gimbal or custom), and then apply rotation.

So for example, it appears that I would not be able to rotate my object in a custom frame using the method given in the link I provided above.

I would greatly appreciate your help!