# Source to read about the math in World Matrix and Blender's use of quaternions?

Tags: transforms, mathematics

I'm going to show some slides about using Blender to illustrate three dimensional and time-evolved physics simulations by just (pasting and) running the python within the blender user interface.

[This really helpful answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44783/5334) showed me how to use a Wold Matrix to do some things, and probably I can keep poking at it until I understand the math behind it, but I am wondering - is there a *source to read about the math in World Matrix and Blender's use of quaternions?*