# How to drive the Scale and Position of the Mapping Node to the value of other Nodes?

Tags: python, materials, uv, node-editor

I want to drive the scale and position respectively by the value of other nodes.

So say I have to use the value of the green nodes in the second image to control the scale of the Mapping Node and the blue nodes to control the position values. How would I do it?

[image: Mapping Node]

[image: Math Node Tree]

I have tried drivers but they seem to not be affected by other nodes even though they can be linked.

Comment: You build your own Mapping node from bunch of Math nodes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40829/7777 with all the inputs nicely exposed.

Comment: So I gave it a shot but you cant really combine the separated vector nodes for scale and position which is what I need. At this point an image sequence might be better than doing it this way but at this point I want to figure it out.

Comment: @Cutis Why you can't combine scale and position? You can combine all the math into one long transform node. Scale first, then rotate, last translation but in the node flow [the order will be reversed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44783/7777).

Comment: Ohh. I was just trying to add them using vector Math. OK that might work