# rotating objects in blender via python

Tags: python

I have the following two lines of code:

```
obj.matrix_world @= translation_matrix @ rotation_mat @ scale_matrix
```

and

```
obj.data.transform(translation_matrix @ rotation_mat @ scale_matrix)
```

They both work, and both appear to do exactly the same thing.  Can somebody explain what the difference(s) between the two are?

Comment: so far, this answer has been illuminating:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44760/rotate-objects-around-their-origin-along-a-global-axis-scripted-without-bpy-op

Comment: One modifies the object transform (first) other modifies the mesh coordinates (second) _akin to object mode rotation vs edit mode rotation_   Result will most likely differ if the starting point of object isn't Identity matrix  (_ie_ when global coords == local coords)